# Entity Framework Relationships Not Returning All Results

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I already deleted the `.edmx` and recreated it multiple times!

Issue is that only some of the `ProductAttributes` (and only for some products and not all) are returning on the following code:

```
   var p = context.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductNumber.Equals(productSku));x.ProductNumber.Equals(productSku));
            foreach (var attr in p.ProductAttributes)
            {
              //only prints some results
            }
```

Where as the follow works fine:

```
   var p = context.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductNumber.Equals(productSku));
            var pAttrs = context.ProductAttributes.Where(x => x.ProductNumber.Equals(productSku));
            foreach (var attr in pAttrs)
            {
               //prints all of the results
            }
```

To ensure that I set the relationships correct here are some screen shots:

[image]

[image]
[image]

**EDIT:**

I did delete a product or two from ProductAttribute who did not have a product, I initally realized that there was no consistency after a database migration. So I attempted to clean the data by eliminating the ProductAttributes with no products. Then put the relationship into play with check existing data set to yes.

I currently just ran the follow queries for both tables. ProductAttribute and Product,

```
  SELECT t1.name
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.name = t1.name
WHERE t2.name IS NULL
```

To find (if T1 is productAttribute) if there are any ProductAttributes with no ProductNumber reference in Product Table. And return 0 rows as result. I assume that means that the ProductAttribute Table has no ProductNumbers that do not appear in Product.

Comment: Are you **deleted some products  yet**? If your are using database first so show  `insert and update specific`

Comment: From `sql server` check your data in database .may be you have **deleted products** and **not delete products attribute**

Comment: Show `Insert And Update specific` in your picture too

Comment: @mohsen I am using Database first, and Update and Insert Settings are both on "No action" Read edit

Comment: Set it to `Cascade`. I have edited answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include  `ProductAttributes` in `Product`

Add below reference

```
using System.Data.Entity
```

And

```
var p = context.Products.Include(p => p.ProductAttributes).FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductNumber.Equals(productSku));
```

**Edit**

This may be you have deleted some products and didn't delete productattributes or somehow there is inconsistancy in database. so you must set insert and update specific to `Cascade`

This will delete ProductAttributes of one product if you delete that product

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EF:

EF by default is using lazy binding, the `ProductAttributes` will not be retrieved from Database until you explicitly specify that.
So try this:

```
var p = context.Products.Include(x => x.ProductAttributes).FirstOrDefault(x => x.ProductNumber.Equals(productSku));
foreach (var attr in p.ProductAttributes)
{
    // This should print out all data
}
```

Comment: Could you make your question clearer? You may put Mandarin if you want.